# Deployment Issue with react 18 node v18 with --openssl-legacy-provider script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, github-pages, netlify

I created an admin app using react to go with my netflix clone app. I am trying to deploy both websites. I am not getting any errors just a blank white screen. My builds are published and I can not figure out why I am getting only a blank white screen.

I am deploying at netlify and on github pages and in both deployments I get the same blank white screen.

I have added in my package.json file "homepage": "http://JohnSolomou.github.io/admin/", and in my scripts I have added this :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start i",
    "build": "react-scripts build --openssl-legacy-provider build i ",
    "predeploy": "npm run build --openssl-legacy-provider build i ",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build --openssl-legacy-provider build i ",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I have installed gh-pages to my dependencies.
I have also chosen the gh-pages in my settings for github pages

Comment: I did notice that with my homepage script when opening this site from my localhost it was also a blank page so I changed it to my login page and works but still having the same deployment issue. changed to this  "homepage": "http://JohnSolomou.github.io/login/",

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My routing didn't match the routing for the deploy, so I just had to add `/admin/` to my home login page, and it worked after a new deployment.

I also changed my homepage url back to what it was in the `package.json` to

```json
"homepage": "http://JohnSolomou.github.io/admin",
```